# Android Beacon Library not seeing any beacons

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I am trying to see (any) BLE beacons (Eddystone) from my android app using the Android Beacon Library, however when I try the sample code found [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html) I am unable to find any beacons.

The code;

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this.getApplicationContext());
    // Detect the main Eddystone-UID frame:
    mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
    mBeaconManager.bind(this);
    Log.d(TAG, "Inside onResume");
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    // Set the two identifiers below to null to detect any beacon regardless of identifiers
    Identifier myBeaconNamespaceId = null;
    Identifier myBeaconInstanceId = null;
    Region region = new Region("my-beacon-region", myBeaconNamespaceId, myBeaconInstanceId, null);
    mBeaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(this);
    try {
        mBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d(TAG, "I detected a beacon in the region with namespace id " + region.getId1() +
            " and instance id: " + region.getId2());
}

public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Inside didExitRegion");
}

public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Inside DidtermineStateForRegion");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mBeaconManager.unbind(this);
}
```

My permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Also when forcing permissions like so;

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { // Android M Permission check
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("This app needs location access");
            builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect beacons.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    }
```

I get no results in my logs. The only logs I receive are;

```
I/CycledLeScanner: Using Android O scanner
I/ScanJob: Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
    Running immediate scan job: instance is org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@35cea01
I/ScanJob: scanJob version 2.15.2 is starting up on the main process
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
    Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
I/ScanJob: Scan job running for 300000 millis
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=10 mScannerId=0
I/ScanHelper: Non-distinct packets detected in a single scan.  Restarting scans unecessary.
I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=124KB, data=96KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=100KB, data=60KB
I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=122KB, data=75KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=122KB, data=75KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

Why am I not able to see my beacons? When using an app like Locate I am able to see them. Is it because I am using SENSORO SmartBeacon-4AA Pro beacons? ([here](https://www.sensoro.com/en/Beacons))

Edit;

When forcefully deleting the app on my phone I see it does enter the functions didDetermineStateForRegion and onResume.

```
I/ScanJob: Scan job running for 300000 millis
I/Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Successfully saved new distance model file
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
I/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Successfully updated distance model with latest from online database
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x782e321000 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x782d1cff40
I/BeaconManager: Cancelling scheduled jobs after unbind of last consumer.
I/ScanJob: Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
I/ScanJob: Using periodicScanJobId from manifest: 208352940
I/ScanJob: Using periodicScanJobId from manifest: 208352940
    onStopJob called for immediate scan org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@ccab959
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BLE: coarse location permission granted
D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19
I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=124KB, data=98KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=101KB, data=55KB
I/ScanJob: Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
I/ScanJob: Using periodicScanJobId from manifest: 208352940
W/JobInfo: Specified interval for 208352940 is +5m0s0ms. Clamped to +15m0s0ms
    Specified flex for 208352940 is 0. Clamped to +5m0s0ms
W/JobInfo: Specified interval for 208352940 is +5m0s0ms. Clamped to +15m0s0ms
    Specified flex for 208352940 is 0. Clamped to +5m0s0ms
D/BLE: Inside DidtermineStateForRegion
    Inside onResume
I/CycledLeScanner: Using Android O scanner
I/ScanJob: Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
I/ScanJob: Running immediate scan job: instance is org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@9fcab08
I/ScanJob: scanJob version 2.15.2 is starting up on the main process
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
I/ScanJob: Scan job running for 300000 millis
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=10 mScannerId=0
I/ScanHelper: Non-distinct packets detected in a single scan.  Restarting scans unecessary.
I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=113KB, data=76KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=113KB, data=76KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

When inside didDetermineStateForRegion the Region object is null.

```
D/BLE: I detected a beacon in the region with namespace id null and instance id: null
```

Comment: Try adding a debug line inside each method: onResume, on BeaconServiceConnect, didDetermineStateForRegion to see which get called.  Also log the value of state in the last method.  (It may be that the value of state is already inside, preventing you from getting a new didEnter callback)

Comment: @davidgyoung I've updated my question with the things you asked.

Comment: Did you get a window asking to access location permission when you first ran the program? Permission was succesfully granted?

Comment: @pb772 yes, it was granted

Comment: OK, but when you get the didDetermineStateForRegion callback, what is the value of state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the didDetermineStateForRegion callback I think beacon was detected, wasn't it? Region and instance were declared as null. If you want to obtain beacon NameSpace and Instance you should do range.

Source:  [How to detect Eddystone-Compatible Beacons](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html)

Comment: I see (which is my beacon) `D/BLE: I see a beacon transmitting namespace id: xxxxxx and instance id: xxxxx approximately 0.02463128532251908 meters away.`. I think my problem was asking for permissions in the activity rather than in my `AndroidManifest`. Weird, as I didn't get a permissions denied error, but how would I get say the Eddystone URL?

Comment: I never used Eddystone Url data format but I think the URL will be on `beacon.getId1();` or `beacon.getId2();` these are the fields which carry information. Ah is 'xxxxx' being displayed at the logcat?

Comment: Ive managed to get it working, but I still don’t know why it didn’t work before. Thanks!